# Force reload of environment variables in IntelliJ... without restarting?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The title says it all.

I have modified an environment variable which is used in my java project via, for example, this line in my pom.xml:

```
<url>${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}</url>
```

For this change to take effect, I must manually restart IntelliJ.

Interestingly, I installed an IntelliJ plugin to "Restart" IntelliJ, which it does, but the environment variables are not refreshed.

Is there a way to do this, without restarting?

Comment: Maybe this is worth writing a plugin for? Just to refresh the environment variables into the current intellij session... it's such a pain to close all intellij windows and restart.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not possible. Once you start a process in Windows or in Unix, you can't read updated environment variables from outside. You can only change environment variables inside your process.

This IntelliJ plugin might not be completely restarting the app, but is i.e. using a different class loader instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It would be nice to have an IntelliJ restart option which perhaps spawns a new operating system process and restarts IntelliJ in that. But for now I understand the reason and I will live with manual restarts :)

Comment: May be putting this into a Maven profile not enabled by default and changing it there could simplify the testing process...

Comment: For Windows 10, command prompt has "refreshenv" command that does this, so it's now technically possible.

Comment: As being mentioned, "you can only change environment variables inside your process" - so you can reread environment like path and change it for your process, like program you are debugging, or change environment option with which you start some new process, and not just in Windows 10.

Answer (score 29):

If you started IntelliJ through "JetBrains Toolbox", then in order to reload the environment variables you need to close them both (IntelliJ & Toolbox), start the toolbox, and then start IntelliJ via the toolbox.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to close the toolbox?

Comment: @vikingsteve RIGHT_CLICK on the system tray icon, then select Exit.

Comment: I didnt know the toolbox existed. Thanks for the heads up! ... Is there any benefit to using the toolbox if IntelliJ is the only Jetbrains product I use?

Comment: @vikingsteve The toolbox will allow for automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to do that without restarting IDE by creating a new local terminal in your IDE, and that does the job.

1. click right bouton in the terminal of the IDE
2. click New session

That worked for me in Pycharm, and the environment variables are reloaded with new paths

Comment: This only updates environment variables for the terminal but not IntelliJ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Intellij caches those veriables even restarted. The Vars in my case has been refreshed after relogin on Windows. Not sure if it does the same on Linux/Mac Os but I worked around it on Windows by going to
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Development -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner.
Then clicked small document icon inside Environment variables textbox. Now while Include system environment variables is ticked I could modify relevant variable or I could add one to User environment variables.
IntelliJ consumed them immediately without restarting/reloading/relogging

Like here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you update an environment variable after Intellij launched, you can't load the latest value within Intellij.

Below is my solution FYR:

0. quit Intellij
1. open a new terminal, ensure the latest updated env var is there
   [image]
2. launch Intellij from this terminal in command line, say, `idea`
3. check the env var in Intellij
   [image]

btw, to use env var in your maven run, follow the steps:

Runs -> Edit Configurations... -> your maven run -> Runner -> Environment variables: -> Include system environment variables:

Good luck~

[image]

[image]

Comment: the question specifically says "without restarting", so your solution is actually not a solution

Answer (score -3):

In Linux/UNIX, possibly a shell can source profile by for example:
. /etc/profile
Refresh the env without exiting the current shell.

Comment: This will not work, as IntelliJ will not pick up any changes to environment variables once it's started up.